# Using an Image to Control the 'Distribute Point on Face' Density?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am having a few issues with the density settings for the distribute points on face node.

So far I have:

- imported an elevation raster for displacement using Blender GIS (top left image)
- Distributed points on face, instanced cubes on them. Works as expected with a set density in the node. (top left and right images)
- imported a raster I want to set density with using the 'basemap on mesh' (UV raster map on existing mesh) import with Blender GIS. I have values that range from 0.02 - 1 (raster image is 20m pixels, 32 bit float). You can see this in the top right image, it maps perfectly to the elevation mesh.

When I try and plug this into the density using Image Texture, I get the result in the lower left corner using 'repeat' extrapolation. I also get errors with 'clip' (no instances) and 'extend' extrapolation. Is there a setting I'm missing...or rather than Image Texture, do I need to use Sample UV, etc? Is there also a way to view the value on an imported image texture to make sure the UV map imported as expected?[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**You have to use the UVMap.** The *Image Texture* node in the *Shader* editor uses automatically the UV map with the camera icon **(1)** if you don't specify a UV map. The default UV map is named *UVMap* as you can see in the *Object Data Properties* tab > *UV Maps* section.

[image: screenshot]

But in the *Geometry Nodes* editor you need to tell the *Image Texture* node which UV map to use. You can do this

- either with **(2)** a *Group Input* (type *Vector*) and specify the name in the *Geometry Nodes* modifier **(3)**, *UVMap* in the example.
- or use **(4)** a *Named Attribute* node (type *Vector*) that creates an *Internal Dependency* **(5)**.

Plug this vector in the *Image Texture* node's *Vector* input slot and set the extrapolation type to *Extend* if you don't want repeats.

(In the example, the *Density* value is multiplied by 500 because the image's color value is between 0.0 and 1.0, and it's far too low for a subdivided default plane.)